# internal representation not hidden in f# module

Tags: module, f#, internals, representation

I'm doing a project, using modules, where I compute images and print them on screen

Everything in my code work just fine, but I'm not quite happy with this inconvenient: in my .fs file (where I define the type and all my functions) I've declared

```
type Picture = P of (Set<((float*float)*(float*float))> * (int*int))
```

Sets describe the points of the segments in the picture (the lines)
and the couple of int is needed to define the bounding box where the image will be shown (width and height)

When I try my function (in another file) I use my grid function

```
let rec setBuilder (ls:((int*int)*(int*int)) list) = 
match ls with
| [] ->  Set.empty
| ((x,y),(w,z))::xs -> setBuilder xs |> Set.add ((float x,float y),(float w, float z)) 

let grid ls (wdt,hgt) = P (setBuilder ls, (wdt, hgt))
```

With this I take a couple/couple int list and build my Picture

The problem is, when I build a Picture with grid (in another file where I try all my function) is visible the internal representation

```
let persn = [((4, 0),(6, 7));  ((6, 7), (6, 10));  ((6, 10), (0, 10));  ((0, 10), (0, 12));   ((0, 12), (6, 12));   ((6, 12), (6, 14));   ((6, 14), (4, 16));   ((4, 16), (4, 18));   ((4, 18), (6, 20));  ((6, 20), (8, 20));
        ((8, 20), (10,18));   ((10, 18), (10, 16));   ((10, 16), (8, 14));   ((8, 14), (8, 12));   ((8, 12), (10, 12));   ((10, 12), (10, 14));   ((10, 14), (12, 14));   ((12, 14), (12, 10));   ((12, 10), (8, 10));   ((8, 10), (8, 8));
        ((8, 8), (10, 0));   ((10, 0), (8, 0));   ((8, 0), (7, 4));   ((7, 4), (6, 0));   ((6, 0), (4, 0))]

let box = (15,20)

let person = grid persn box
```

when I interpret the last line I get from the console

```
val person : Picture =
P (set
[((0.0, 10.0), (0.0, 12.0)); ((0.0, 12.0), (6.0, 12.0));
((4.0, 0.0), (6.0, 7.0)); ((4.0, 16.0), (4.0, 18.0));
((4.0, 18.0), (6.0, 20.0)); ((6.0, 0.0), (4.0, 0.0));
((6.0, 7.0), (6.0, 10.0)); ((6.0, 10.0), (0.0, 10.0));
((6.0, 12.0), (6.0, 14.0)); ...], (15, 20))
```

there is a way to hide this information, I looked up and the solution seems to be the tagged value (but I'm already using them)

*** EDIT ***

I noticed that this behavior could be associated with the static member in my implementation files, without them the inner type is not shown

```
type Picture with
 static member(*)  (c:float,pic:Picture) =
        match pic with 
        | P(set,(wdt,hgt)) ->  P (Set.map (fun ((x,y),(w,z)) -> ((x*c,y*c),(w*c,z*c))) set, (int (round (float wdt * c)) ,int (round (float hgt * c))))   


 static member(|>>)  (pic1:Picture,pic2:Picture) =
        match pic1,pic2 with
         (P (set1,(w1,h1)), P (set2,(w2,h2))) ->   let new_p2 = (((float h1/ float h2)) * pic2) 
                                                   match new_p2 with 
                                                   P (nset2,(nw2,nh2)) -> P(Set.union set1 (Set.map (fun ((x,y),(w,z)) -> ((x + (float w1) ,y),(w + (float w1), z)) ) nset2),(w1 + nw2, h1)) 


 static member(|^^)  (pic1:Picture,pic2:Picture) =
        match pic1,pic2 with
        (P (set1,(w1,h1)), P (set2,(w2,h2))) ->  let new_pic2 = (((float  w1/ float w2)) * pic2)
                                                 match new_pic2 with
                                                 P (nset2,(nw2,nh2)) -> P(Set.union set1 (Set.map (fun ((x,y),(w,z)) -> ((x,(float h1) + y),(w,(float h1) + z)) ) nset2),(w1 , h1 + nh2))

 static member (>||>) (n, pic:Picture) =
        match n with
        | 0 ->  pic
        | m ->  pic |>> ((m-1) >||> pic)


 static member (^||^) (n, pic:Picture) =
      match n with
      | 0 -> pic
      | m -> pic |^^ ((m-1) ^||^ pic)
```

Comment: In functional programming you usually don't hide the internal representation of data. Why do you want to hide it? Is it purely for convenience when using FSI, or is because of how you want to structure your program?

Comment: If you prefer FSI to not show the last expression's value you can always add another expression after that like `()`. There is also a `--quiet` option when invoking `fsi.exe` that suppresses all output except what you explicitly print out.

Comment: I want the type to be hidden because is a request of the exercise

Comment: What makes you think that it's not hidden?

Comment: I know it's shown because when I try to use my function in a separate file (I'm a user in that case who is not suppose to know how I managed to implements my .fsi file) and create a Picture with my grid function, in the interpreter console it shows me that P is a couple (set + (int, int))

Answer (score 2):

Simply write `type Picture = private P of ...` then other modules cannot see the internal of `Picture`.

Note: if you write `type private Picture = P of ...` it means that other modules cannot see the `Picture` type.

Comment: Hmm, it's strange. Please check my demo code [here](https://rextester.com/SPI89811). If the `private` keyword is there, we have a compiler error because we are trying access the internal of the type from other modules. Removing the keyword then the error goes away. Maybe your F# version is too old?

Comment: i'll try as soon as i can, ty
Yhea it could be the version, yesterday i updated monodevelop but before that I was running the version downloaded in march of this year